# Hunch authentication on android phone redirect

Tags: java, android, authentication, oauth, hunch

I am working authentication on an android phone which sends the user to Hunch to authentication after clicking a log in button. This sets up a new intent as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri data = Uri.parse("hunch.com/authorize/v1/?app_id=1234&next=hoosheer-hunch-app://");
    intent.setData(data);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This is my manifest file

```
<activity android:name="hunch" android:label="hunch">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="hoosheer-hunch-app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It gives me this error:

```
04-12 17:04:22.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=hunch.com/authorize/v1/?app_id=1234&next=hoosheer-hunch-app:// }
```

But I have similar code working for logging in using Foursquare. The hunch.java class contains an `onResume` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hunch does not currently support custom URL schemes such as `hoosheer-hunch-app://`

Until we implement this functionality you should use the following URL to authenticate:

> http://hunch.com/authorize/v1/?app_id=1234&next=/

After authorizing your application, the user will be redirected to

> http://hunch.com/?auth_token_key=4d3d3d3d3&user_id=hn_5678&next=%2F

You should monitor the ACTION_VIEW Intent for the URL change, pull the `auth_token_key` out of the URL, and then exchange it for an `auth_token` using the [get-auth-token](http://hunch.com/developers/v1/docs/reference/#get-auth-token) API call.